# how to add em space (&emsp;) after BR tag using CSS

Tags: html, css, line-breaks, text-indent

I want to add an em-space just after BR tag so as to achieve text-indent effect. But the following STYLE doesn't work on my Chrome.

Or, any other way to achieve text-indent effect after BR tag?

```
<style>
br::after { 
  content: "&emsp;";
}
</style>

<p>Note:<br>For this selector to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declared, and you must use the old, single-colon CSS2 syntax (:after instead of ::after).</p>
```

Comment: Note that `::after` inserts as the [last child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) of the selected element, not after the element.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this to add an em space just after BR tag!

```
<style>
br {
  content: '';
  white-space: pre;
}

br::after { 
  content: "\A\2003";
}
</style>
```

Another problem is that I also want to keep 1em margin-bottom. The following style ALONE works well.

```
<style>
br {
  content: '';
  display: block; 
  margin-bottom: 1em; 
}
</style>
```

BUT, if i mixed the two styles into the following, it doesn't work!!!

```
<style>
br {
  content: '';
  white-space: pre;
  display: block; 
  margin-bottom: 1em; 
}

br::after { 
  content: "\A\2003";
}
</style>
```

Comment: I mean, you shouldn't be using BR tags like this. This is basically exactly what the `text-indent` property is for, besides.

Comment: This worked perfectly for what I wanted (indent after content added in a ::before selector) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You really shouldn't be using a line break (br) tag to break up paragraphs, not in modern web design. See the [HTML 5.2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/textlevel-semantics.html#the-br-element) for some examples.

Furthermore, there is a CSS property `text-indent` which also achieves the text indentation you are after.

Basically, use `<p>` as intended (eg to wrap a paragraph) and then apply `text-indent` to the `p` tags.

```css
p {
  text-indent: 1em;
}
p.unindented {
  text-indent: inherit;
}
```

```html
<p class="unindented">Note:</p>
<p>For this selector to work in IE8, a DOCTYPE must be declared, and you must use the old, single-colon CSS2 syntax (:after instead of ::after).</p>
<p>Here is another paragraph to show how this applies when you have more than one &lt;p&gt; of content. The text-indent property is supported by all major browsers. (That is, IE 3 and later. Not that IE is a major browser anymore....)</p>
<p>See here for more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent</p>
```

`text-indent` is a very old property with wide support across all major browsers and a lot of older ones too. It was first introduced in IE 3, to give a sense of how old it is. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) for more information.

Comment: This is a frame challenge, because BR tags should not be used like this, and there is a built-in way to do text indentation that has been around forever.